# Linux sendmail fails when relaying to a named server - but where is that server name configured (CentOS)?

Tags: centos, sendmail

An application on one of our servers has recently started to fail when sending emails. It is configured to use /usr/sbin/sendmail. Checking the mail log shows the following information:

```
Apr 16 17:00:05 myserver sendmail[17721]: x3GF0512312312721: to=me@myaddress.net, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30023, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (x3GF0512312312721 Message accepted for delivery)

Apr 16 17:02:05 myserver sendmail[17724]: x3GF023123123722: to=<me@myaddress.net>, ctladdr=<root@myserver.myaddress.net> (0/0), delay=00:02:00, xdelay=00:02:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120307, relay=lxmail.mailprovider.org. [10.11.5.103], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with lxmail.mailprovider.org.
```

Our mail provider has recently added some new SMTP servers and decommissioned some old ones, so I suspect that somewhere is a configuration pointing at the old SMTP server.

However, I cannot find a single reference to mailprovider.org in any of the config files for sendmail. I have confirmed that sendmail is indeed the process listening on port 25 and the log file shows that sendmail has tried to send to mailprovider.org - but how is sendmail deciding to try mailprovider.org when it doesn't appear in a single sendmail config file?

Where else could this relay destination be configured?

I've tried

```
> grep -Porn "mailprovider" /etc/mail
```

and received no results.

How can I change the relay destination?

Comment: That email address, hostname and IP address look fake. You probably will need to [disclose the real information](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632).

Comment: Assuming myaddress.net's MX is mailprovider there may be some cached MX RRs somewhere or your mail provider did not update their MXs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if you have a bad address on your local DNS with an nslookup or dig request (check /etc/resolv.conf for where your server is looking) or a static map host entry in /etc/hosts.